# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator' has no attribute 'inpus'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to use linear classifier to predict, the constructing and training of the estimator is listed here:

```
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
  n_classes = 2,
  model_dir = "ongoing",
  feature_columns = categorical_features + continuous_features
(
FEATURES = ['Age', 'Gender', 'ICD9Code']
LABEL = 'Condition'

def get_input_fn(data_set, num_epochs, n_batch, shuffle):
    input = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
       x = pd.DataFrame({k: data_set[k].values for k in FEATURES}),
       y = pd.Series(data_set[LABEL].values),
       batch_size = n_batch,
       num_epochs = num_epochs,
       shuffle = shuffle
     )
     return input
model.train(
  input_fn = get_input_fn(csv_data, num_epochs = None, n_batch = 10461, shuffle = False
  ),
  steps = 1000
)
predict_data = pd.read_csv('feature_condition.csv', usecols = ['PatientGuid', 'Age', 'Gender', 'ICD9Code'], nrows = 5)
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inpus.numpy_input_fn(
                      x = {"x": predict_data},
                      y = None,
                      batch_size = 5,
                      shuffle = False,
                  num_threads = 5
                   )
predict_results = model.predict(predict_input_fn)
print(predict_results)
```

got the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator' has no attribute 'inpus'
```

my tensorflow version is 2.4.1

can you please help me to resolve this problem? THX!

update: I have already corrected the typo error, and the error has been fixed, but I got one warning listed here:

```
The name tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn instead.
```

after I used the suggested function, I got the same wanring listed here:

```
The name tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn instead
```

It really confused me, can you please help to fix it? THX!

I uploaded my complete code in google drive, this is the link here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R6bRcv8Afjx4cPLBZaBpuCcDg71fNN3Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you change `tf.estimator.inpus.numpy_input_fn` to `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` and try? It's typo error.

Comment: I corrected this error and the error is resolved, but one warning is presented: 'The name tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn instead.' when I used this suggested function, the terminal still shows the same warning. Do you know how to fix it? THX!

Comment: Can you let us know warning message? Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I added it in my question, please have a look

Comment: Can you restart your kernel and try again? Your code is not complete here to replicate the issue. If you can provide complete code it's easy to debug.

Comment: well, I use terminal not ide to run the code, it seems that I cannot restart the kernel in the terminal, and I also restarted the terminal, the warning is not resolved. I uploaded the complete in google drive, the link is added in my question's end. Can you please have a look? Hope it would be clear.

Comment: You can ignore all those warnings (`i.e deprecated messages`) and they are from source code files not from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue can be resolved if you can change `tf.estimator.inpus.numpy_input_fn` to `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn`. It's typo error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import json
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from tensorflow.train import SequenceExample, FeatureLists
from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers


csv_file = 'feature_condition.csv'
csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory = False)
csv_df = pd.DataFrame(csv_data)

test_file = 'test.csv'
test_data = pd.read_csv(test_file, low_memory = False)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)



CONTI_FEATURES = ['Age']
CATE_FEATURES = ['Gender', 'ICD9Code']

# create the feature column:
continuous_features = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in CONTI_FEATURES]

categorical_features = [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(k, hash_bucket_size = 1000) for k in CATE_FEATURES]


model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
  n_classes = 2,
  model_dir = "ongoing",
  feature_columns = categorical_features + continuous_features
)

FEATURES = ['Age', 'Gender', 'ICD9Code']
LABEL = 'Condition'

# input function:
def get_input_fn(data_set, num_epochs, n_batch, shuffle):
    input = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
       x = pd.DataFrame({k: data_set[k].values for k in FEATURES}),
       y = pd.Series(data_set[LABEL].values),
       batch_size = n_batch,
       num_epochs = num_epochs,
       shuffle = shuffle
     )
    return input
# train the model
model.train(
  input_fn = get_input_fn(csv_data, num_epochs = None, n_batch = 10461, shuffle = False
  ),
  steps = 1000
)

# iterate every data in test dataset and make a prediction:
row_pre = 0
for i in test_data.loc[:,'PatientGuid']:
    dict = {'Age': test_data.loc[row_pre]['Age'],
            'Gender': test_data.loc[row_pre]['Gender'],
            'ICD9Code': test_data.loc[row_pre]['ICD9Code'],
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict, index = [1,2,3])
    predict_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    #predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(

                          x = {k: df[k].values for k in FEATURES},
                          y = None,
                          batch_size = 1,
                          num_epochs = 1,
                          shuffle = False,
                          num_threads = 1
                       )
    predict_results = model.predict(predict_input_fn)
    row_pre += 1
```

You can ignore deprecated warnings.

Comment: @RA.IBOY, If it answers your question, kindly accept and upvote it. Thanks!